# Join a column located in Struct with an another column located in another table

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two tables using spark-sql but between a column located in struct and an another column, to do this, I made :

```
 val prs = sc.read.json(dir+"/prs.json")
  prs.createGlobalTempView("prs")

  val st = sc.read.json(dir+"/struct.json")
  st.createGlobalTempView("struct")

  prs.join(st,"entclasses.struct").show
```

Input files : 
pers :

```
{"nom":"hamdane","prenom":"mounir", "entclasses":[{"struct":"526","classe":"501","mef":"20114"},{"cle":"5174","classe":"5581","mef":"201012414"}]}
{"nom":"hamdanes","prenom":"mounirs", "entclasses":[{"struct":"52614","classe":"501","mef":"20114"},{"cle":"5174","classe":"5581","mef":"201012414"}]}
```

Struct:

```
{"cle":"526","df":"125"}
{"cle":"5174","df":"015"}
{"cle":"5581","df":"105"}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what do you want as a final output?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala I want to check if a person have or not a struct ( attribute struct - > cle)